# Tomcat 9 on RHEL 9.3 systemctl service fails: cannot touch '$CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory

Tags: tomcat9, systemctl, catalina, catalina.out, rhel9

Tomcat starts successfully when run from the tomcat user in RHEL 9.3 using $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh. I am using for my java:

java version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58, mixed mode, sharing)

I have created a service, called tomcat.service under /usr/lib/systemd/system thus:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat webserver
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21-oracle-x64
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.85
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=$CATALINA_HOME
Environment=CLASSPATH=$CATALINA_HOME/lib
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true'

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

ExecStart=/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.85/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.85/bin/shutdown.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This fails with the strange error:

startup.sh[317989]: touch: cannot touch '$CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
startup.sh[317983]: /home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.85/bin/catalina.sh: line 504: $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out: No such>

I've checked and the CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out file exists and is owned by tomcat

Clearly the service must have successfully started the startup.sh script, but for some reason seems to be having issues trying to write to this file

Any suggestions gratefully accepted

Expected the service to start as executing the script did